# Database Project over Babelfish

Tags: babelfish

Has anyone had any luck publishing a VS Database Project over Babelfish? There is nothing on the net related to publishing .dacpac over BabelFish.

I can connect and query via new query in SSMS, however, connection fails while attempting to publish a DB project?

I am assuming there is missing functionality in TDS translation, and this does not fall with Babelfish's "most" tds commands are supported. Also, I am thinking that a Data-tier Application relies on more than just tds translation, there are server-side binaries that are part of the process which may be outside of the babel fish realm.

Would like confirmation from someone who has been down this road though.